# Webcam in emulator 2.0 Android Studio not run

Tags: android, webcam

Hi I'm trying to access the webcam the notebook via the webcam emulator and puts me

> You can access the camera.

The webcam works in other settings within the emulator but not.

But I tried it in different emulators and does not work. When you start the emulator if the display device appears webcam but then it does not work.

Let's see if someone can help me, Thanks